# MFMessageComposeViewController disable add recipients button

Tags: ios, objective-c, sms, message, contact-list

I have a `MFMessageComposeViewController` witch i pre define its `body` and `recipients` fields.

I want to disable the **add more contact button** "see the attached screen shot" because i just want the user to send this message to 1 pre defined number.

How can accomplish that. Thanks.

[image: MFMessageComposeViewController Screen]

Answer (score 0):

From Apple documentation of [MFMessageComposeViewController](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MessageUI/Reference/MFMessageComposeViewController_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009668-CH1-DontLinkElementID_1)

> Important: The message composition interface itself is not
>   customizable and must not be modified by your app. In addition, after
>   presenting the interface, your app is unable to make further changes
>   to the message content. The user can edit the content using the
>   interface, but programmatic changes are ignored. Thus, you must set
>   the values of content fields, if desired, before presenting the
>   interface

Comment: Since iOS7, is there any way to do that ?